Conjecture: Definite existence of a prime number in the range of ${[|3^{p_i}−k\times{p_i};3^{p_i}+k\times{p_i}|]}$
My old post was closed while I had clearly tried to explain at my best. So I'll retry without posting outer links and reexplaining at most details what this conjecture is about, which was a research that I did 7 years ago when I was a college student for fun. But since I wasn't in math field I couldn't finish the work so I hope if someone is interested, who's got interest in prime numbers, to take it over if he find this explanation below convincing.
Note: this post What is the appropriate way to post conjectures on Math.SE clearly says that I can post conjecture here if I understand, as long as I provide enough details to make it interesting.
Origin and problematic
The spark of idea came from Bertrand's postulate, which are these 3 formulas:

${\forall n\in \mathbb {N};n > 3;\exists p\in \mathbb {P} :\qquad  n<p<2n-2.}$


${\forall n\in \mathbb {N};n > 1;\exists p\in \mathbb {P} :\qquad  n<p<2n.}$


${for~~{n}\geqslant 1:\qquad  p_{n+1}<2p_n.}$

What I noticed, back at that time and if I wasn't wrong since I wasn't that versed in maths. Is that this theorem was the most precise theorem for ensuring that there exist primes in a certain range.
I take n = 200, I'm sure I'll find primes between 200 and 400
I take n = ${2^{10}}$, I'm sure I'll find primes between ${2^{10}}$ and ${2\times2^{10}}$
Now the problem is when the scale become higher, which means the digits are growing, 100 digits, 10 to power of a huge n digits, etc. I can take a number ${a}$ which has like 100 digits, and according to the theorem, I'm sure to find a prime between ${a}$ and ${2a}$. But I have no idea where that next prime is, it could be the next 2 numbers after ${a}$, it could be the next 10k number, it could be after 1 million number(well I doubt), etc ... Because the search range is so big.
We can sumarize this into two issues:

the maximum range search is too big
there is no minimum range search

Note : While writing this, just found out that the theorem got some precision improvements, which gives a better search range but still it's considered a bit big. Example for using ${\displaystyle x<p\leq \left(1+{\frac {1}{5\,000\ln ^{2}{x}}}\right)x}$. I can input a number ${468,991,632,168,991,632}$ which has 18 digits, and the other side will give me approximately ${468,991,688,823,352,400}$ which has 18 digits. The search range here is ${56,654,360,768}$ numbers.
Too much for introducing the problematic, let me share with you some few examples of what I did research:
Observations
Back at the time I wanted to narrow my research only on ${prime^{prime}}$ to find out of there are any special relationships, I ended up only testing values of ${3^{prime}}$ because it took a huge time. (now creating the table and copying values from wikiversity to here is such a pain)



prime number ${p_i}$
${3^{p_i}}$
distance from next prime
next prime
distance from previous prime
previous prime




2
9
2
11
2
7


3
27
2
29
4
23


5
243
8
251
2
241


7
2187
16
2203
8
2179


11
117 147
16
117 163
14
117 133


13
1 594 323
8
1 594 331
22
1 594 301


17
129 140 163
34
129 140 197
4
129 140 159


19
1 162 261 467
56
1 162 261 523
14
1 162 261 453


23
..... 178 827
32
...178 859
20
.178 807


29
...... 364 883
30
...365 013
14
...364 869


31
...... 283 947
16
...283 963
4
...283 943


37
...... 997 363
50
...997 413
2
...997 361


41
...... 786 403
70
...786 473
2
...786 401


43
...... 077 627
52
...077 679
74
.077 553


47
...... 287 787
52
...287 839
46
..287 741


53
...... 796 723
26
...796 749
4
...796 719


59
...... 811 067
64
...811 131
38
...811 029


61
...... 299 603
34
...299 637
74
...299 529


67
...... 410 587
230
...410 817
298
...410 289


71
...... 257 547
20
...257 567
20
...257 527



Note: I couldn't put all what I tested in wikiversity, it was a true pain to already calculate and compare at that time so all the other tests I've done were with pen and paper and online tools to calculate. I have tested all powers from ${3^{2}}$ till ${3^{257}}$. The last one has like between 120 and 128 digits. Even the last one in this table above has 34 digits
During all these tests, I have concluded these observations:

I could definitely, from ${3^{2}}$ till ${3^{257}}$, find a prime number in a range of ${[|3^{p}−3{p}~~;~~3^{p}+3{p}|]}$. Except for  ${3^{67}}$ which was ${[|3^{p}−4{p}~~;~~3^{p}+4{p}|]}$
so that means, for a huge number like ${3^{257}}$ which has 123 digits, I can find at least one prime in a range of ${[|3^{257}−3\times{257}~~;~~3^{257}+3\times{257}|]}$, which is a search range of 1542 numbers, and that's for a very huge number

Hypotheses
Now I would have been happier if ${3^{67}}$ didn't interfere that badly so that the multiplier could be stuck at 3, sadly. So I can put 2 hypotheses:

The first hypothese : The multiplier, at it's minimum range, can be considered 3. If multiple occurences after ${3^{257}}$ denies that possibility. That means either we increment the multiplier value (named ${k}$ by one everytime, like going from  ${[|3^{p}−3{p}~~;~~3^{p}+3{p}|]}$ to ${[|3^{p}−4{p}~~;~~3^{p}+4{p}|]}$ then ${[|3^{p}−5{p}~~;~~3^{p}+5{p}|]}$. Or that there could be a condition for the k to be incremented to a certain number
The second hypothese : I can maximise, definitely, until proven wrong, the value of ${k}$ to be the given prime number. Which means that the maximum range would be ${[|3^{p}−p\times{p}~~;~~3^{p}+p\times{p}|]}$ => ${[|3^{p}−{p^2}~~;~~3^{p}+{p^2}|]}$. Taking the ${3^{257}}$ and supposing that I didn't find the minimum. I can assume that max range would be ${[|3^{257}−{257^2}~~;~~3^{257}+{257^2}|]}$. ${257^2}$ = 66 049 so that means the search range would be 132 098 which is so incredible as a search range for a 123 digits number

In a nutshell:

Using the min value : ${\displaystyle \forall p_i\in \mathbb {P} ;\exists {p}\in \mathbb {P} ;\exists {k}\in \mathbb {N^*}; (2 < k < p_i):~~ p\in [|3^{p_i}−k{p_i}~~;~~3^{p_i}+k{p_i}|]}$

Using the max value : ${\displaystyle \forall p_i\in \mathbb {P} ;\exists {p}\in \mathbb {P} :~~ p\in [|3^{p_i}−{p_i}^2~~;~~3^{p_i}+{p_i}^2|]}$


Like I've said, I was able to test only the powers of 3. So I wonder if maybe other primes to primes powers could have possibly, at least that max search range, based on the given prime.
So finally, why do I think that this research may be valuable:

Having a good search range and existence of a minimum prime number, based on primes numbers. especially for huge numbers
Possibility of application of these idea to other primes to the power of primes.
Unlocking another prime to prime relationship
Minimising the search range for prime numbers that are huge

You who are far more proficients in Math than I, and me who forgot a lot of advanced maths because I'm in another career. I really think this conjecture has a potential and would like to know if you think that this can be ever needed in math or no.
Thanks for reading, if you have any questions or remarks, don't hesitate. Although like I've said I've forgotten most of the advanced stuffs

See prime gaps.

You may find OEIS sequences A013598 and A013604 to be of interest.

@Peter You mean upper bound for a prime gap.  The lower bound is $2$.

@RobertIsrael Yes , a humiliating error , thank you for pointing it out.

Failures for $k=2$ : $67,311,449,953$ the necessary $k$ is $3$ excetpf for $67$ for which it is $4$.

Both prime gaps have an expectation of $p_1\cdot \ln(3)$ which is slightly larger than $p_1$ , so I guess , $k=1$ fails often , probably infinite many often.

For $1889$ , we have the next case where $k=3$ is necessary.

my bad i did a mistake, i wanted to say the minimum k to test for was 3*, i'll correct that, thanks for your remarks

Just read the prime gap in wiki, well ofc I couldn't understand it completely but in this case we have a gap between a prime and a non prime, which is if i'm not wrong unrelated. but thanks i learned something new :)

The relation between this and prime gaps is this: If there is no prime in an interval $[a,b]$, the gap between the greatest prime $< a$ and the next prime, which is the least prime $> b$, is greater than $b-a$.

As a first approximation, we may hypothesise that primes near powers of $3$ behave similarly to primes in any other region of the same order of magnitude:
the probability that a particular number $n$ is prime is approximately $1/\ln(n)$.  The expected number of primes in the interval $[3^m - km, 3^m + km]$ should then be approximately $\frac{2km}{\ln(3^m)} = \frac{2k}{\ln(3)}$.  If (again as a rough heuristic) we model this number as a Poisson random variable with this expected value, the probability that there is at least one such prime would be $1 - \exp\left(-2k/\ln(3)\right)$.  Since this does not depend on $m$, we should expect that for any given $k$ there will be infinitely many $m$ for which there are no primes in the interval $[3^m - km, 3^m + km]$.
On the other hand, the expected number of primes in the interval $[3^m - m^2, 3^m + m^2]$ would be approximately $\frac{2 m^2}{\ln(3^m)} = \frac{2m}{\ln(3)}$,
and the probability of at least one such prime would be $1 - \exp\left(-2m/\ln(3)\right)$.  Since $\sum_m \exp(-2m/\ln(3))$ converges, we should expect
that for all but finitely many (and quite likely for all) $m$ there should be at least one prime in the interval.
Of course, all this is just heuristics and nowhere near a proof.

Interesting method, so does that mean heuristically, that for at least small primes powered, like ${2^{p}}$ or  ${5^{p}}$ till 1k or even a bit more, the convergence would be still on ? due to the fact that the ln function is most known for reducing values
So at least we have like a good idea, that the upper bound with k as the related prime  can be real right ?

The argument would be similar with $3$ replaced by any other integer $> 1$.  The fact that $3$ is prime is irrelevant.

That is, for any $t > 1$ we should expect that there is at least one prime in the interval $[t^m - m^2, t^m + m^2]$ for all but finitely many $m$, but for any $k$ there are infinitely many $m$ for which there are no primes in $[t^m - k m, t^m + k m]$.

wait wait, so, potentially, for every real number > 1, we can also expect at least one prime in that upper bound interval except for some numbers which % is a bit low/unknown but not that big ?
supposing it's the majority, we can have high hope that this can greatly outperform other theorems about the search range of prime for larger numbers ? (well ofc limited with condition that we have to power the number to a prime)
I still wonder if the probability will still converge when what's inside the ln tends to inf

I think the base number should rather be for  less than 100 maybe even less than 10. Taking a big number with small power might not give the wanted results. So maybe sticking for base numbers between 1 and 9 (even 10). Maybe even there could be some kind of a hidden param that balances the proportionality when the base number is bigger than the power
